# Call jQuery on buttonclick

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run some jQuery code when I click a button, but I can't make even the most simple example work.

My jQuery code is this:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });

</script>
```

and my html looks like this

```
<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="button" />
</div>
```

but when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: when I paste this code into jsFiddle it works: http://jsfiddle.net/UVSzk/ what browser are you using? any particular reason you're using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Why do you use such an ancient jQuery version?

Comment: because i already had it, and knowing very little about jquery i didn't know it was ancient.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

wrap your code inside a document.ready function

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

or put your script code right before the end of the body tag

You need to wait for the elements to be available the dom on page load before binding event handlers

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
       alert('click event');
    });
});
```

If this does not work make sure you included jquery correct.

If you are unsure try the following.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the event after the DOM has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try your function in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code with document when ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: Why copy pasting another answer? What's the point of it?